# R regex for control ascii characters

Tags: r, non-ascii-characters

I want to detect the presence of `ASCII` control characters in my text file , excluding the control characters CR and LF

i am trying

```
grepl("[\x01-\x09\x11-\x12\x14-\x1F\x7F]",file$text)
```

where a sample file text looks like

[image]

but when i run the above grepl , i get the result as TRUE whereas i should be getting a False.

Sample text (open in `notepad+`)

Basically i want to detect the presence of ASCII SYMBOLS , except for CR and LF
[image]

Comment: can you maybe add `dput(file$text)` to your question or the code to create `file`?

Comment: I am not able to provide you the exact text as the ascii control characters are removed when i try to paste the data here. Basically it should look like the data in the screenshot  CAN SYN etc are control ascii characters and I would like to detect the presence of these control characters in the file

Comment: `grepl("[\x01-\x09\x11-\x12\x14-\x1F\x7F]",file$text)` on these lines gives `FALSE` for all lines but the one that contains the control chars. It seems to work as expected.